# What is "Following through someone else's move"?

Tags: apocalypse-world

Apocalypse World playbook's optional battle moves include a move called "follow through on someone else's move". Sadly, while there are plenty of examples for the usual moves, the optional battle moves don't have any, so it's hard to tell when the move is supposed to be used.

So, what exactly is "following through" on someone's move, and how is it different from the usual "Help / interfere" move? Examples on actions and situations that are "following through" are especially welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## A prelude to an answer

First, critically, there is a rule you have to follow as MC:

> If these battle moves don't make immediate sense to you, don't use them. If you do use them, use them only to supplement, not to replace or supersede, the basic moves. (*AW*, p. 214)

What's this mean? I mean, you're asking here and hoping to understand the moves, so that's OK, right? No, not exactly.

What this means is that, if you're MCing Apocalypse World and you don't know what a battle move is for, that battle move's triggering fiction *does not exist in your apocalypse*. It means that there's no relevant **fiction** for the move to trigger off, because your awesome, creative MC mind is busy with other stuff that's not touching on anything relevant to this battle move.

Since Apocalypse World is a relentlessly fiction-first, moves-second design, anything that isn't in the game as fiction already cannot and *must* not be shoehorned into the game mechanically. If you don't get a particular battle move, then relevant fiction simply isn't ever going to come up.

So, if you don't see a use for this move, you must not try to use it. And that's OK: because the moves exist only to give mechanical teeth to existing fiction that is already fully understood and present; you've got no reason to strain to use it anyway. If, for example, your apocalypse never involves threats of violence (to pick an absurd example), then it would be theoretically OK to never understand **go aggro** and **seize by force** moves — as they'll never be triggered and used. That's an absurd example (and to be clear, that quoted rule doesn't apply to basic moves, just battle moves, and you *should* understand the basic moves before MCing), but I hope it demonstrates that a move triggered only by fiction that doesn't and won't exist in a particular apocalypse means the move won't and can't be used.

The same goes for **follow through on someone else's move**: if it never happens fictionally, the move will never trigger and you don't need to get it.

And if you're concerned at this point that, by not including the move, you're somehow missing out on the full game or limiting the players: don't worry about that. If the move is ever useful, it will be super-obvious because you'll be looking down the muzzle of some explosively-awesome fiction that either makes it *obvious right now* how to use that move to create more awesomeness, or you'll play through some awesome battle-y fiction and, after the fight, you'll have an insight about what **follow through** is for.

That's the corollary of the quoted rule: you'll understand battle moves more once you see some fictional battles actually unfold in your apocalypse. You can MC battles entirely with basic moves, so use the basic moves and the battle moves you really get, and after the dust settles, you might have an epiphany and know what to do with **follow through** next time a battle breaks out. That's cool, and part of how all the optional rules are optional.

## What it does mean: Coordinated tactics and building on momentum

With that preamble out of the way, here's what the move is for. Just because this is here though, doesn't mean the rule I quote in the preamble can be ignored: if you only kinda get what the move is for after this explanation, it's still not a move you should use. Critically, the battle moves are super-optional, and only to be used when you 100% know it's the right move to use right now *and* there are no regular moves that should be used instead, since those always take precedence over battle moves.

Following through on someone else's move in a battle means *using* situation it creates to turn the tide or create even more momentum with something *new*: some possibility that their move opened up. It's not **help** — that would be just helping (present tense) to try to achieve the exact same thing — it's letting them do their thing on their own, *not* helping, and using the initiative, momentum, or opening they've already created (past tense) to do something new and create an even bigger swing in the battle.

So you're in a firefight with Dustwich's wacko cult-gang and they're in a hardened position — the last two walls of the only remaining ground floor an old Brutalist concrete office tower, reinforced with layers of rusty sheet metal to create firing positions covering the wider valley you're advancing up towards them. They've got lots of guns, a score of warm bodies to hold them, and kill zones set up. Your Hardholder and gang are pinned down in a ditch within firing range of them and can't get closer or retreat without suffering useless casualties. You're with the hold's scouts and hunters back beyond bullet range. You could flank the building easy and get at its crumbled-open unprotected right side, if you didn't have to cross multiple kill zones to get there.

That's the situation. Now let's say your Hardholder Mom orders her gang to empty their magazines, just throw everything they've got at the enemy, to create a minute or so of intense covering fire. They know they can't actually hit anyone because the enemy fire teams are in secure positions and can just duck down and be fancy-free, but it will force them to stop firing. At the expense of being completely out of ammo and screwed, of course. Now, the key here is that they're not trying to retreat — they're suppressing the kill zones for a minute or two, they're opening an opportunity in the battle.

That's when your let go your bunch of savages and charge around Dustwich's flank. That's **following through on Mom's move**: you're not helping them at all, you're taking advantage of a shift in the battle that move creates, and creating more momentum.

So you make the move, hit on the roll, and the MC's a fan and tells you that the result is *you dominate someone's position*. You've got your scouts and hunters around the flank and you've got fire lanes straight into the guts of their position now. Not only are they pinned from the remainder of Mom and gang's covering fire, but now if they so much as breathe a hint of moving, covering fire or no, you and yours can put bullets in their heads.

Now that's following through.

But now suppose your Brainer Iris has been hanging out in the Maelstrom, and from a previous set of events has figured out how to ask it to pretty-please broadcast a message at the expense of getting unceremoniously dumped out of the Maelstrom and taking 1-Ψ-harm. (Not involving a move either, just choose-and-it-happens.) Iris tells Dustwich and the cult-gang to drop their guns in the building and walk out to surrender, or be wiped out. You might figure this is following through on *your* move, but it isn't because it's **manipulation** and **follow through** never supersedes a basic move. So Iris rolls+sharp to see what Dustwich and followers do, and the apocalypse rolls onward.

But if battle moves can't supersede basic moves, you might wonder why your **follow through** above was allowed, because couldn't that flanking maneuver be **acting under fire**, with the fire being, I dunno, not getting there before Mom runs out of ammo and Dustwich figures out they're empty and the kill zones come back up? Well no, because, it's already been established that Mom's got a minute or two of ammo for the withering cover fire, and it won't take that long to get into position. Hence, under normal circumstances that wouldn't be a move at all to get there and you would just do it. Since it's a tactical maneuver, in battle, capitalising on the opportunity created by Mom though, the outcome is neatly handled by **follow through**.

### Isn't that really, really niche?

Yeah, it is. That's why you don't ever need to actually use the battle moves, and why the rule exists that the MC can't use a battle move if they don't understand what it's for. These moves are super-niche and situational, and your game isn't going to be missing anything for not using them.

If they come up, they come up. If they don't, that's totally cool.

### Get it? Got it. Good.

So if that made a switch flip and a light bulb go off in your head, and you really *get* the kind of tactical maneuvering that fulfills the *to do it, do it* rule of triggering **follow through**, then you're good to go.

If it's still kind of murky, but now you have some kind of idea of why the move even exists even if you're not sure you'd ever need it, then that's cool — you won't need it in your apocalypse and don't need to de-murk it further. Not everyone has a feel for how battles ebb and flow, not everyone gets all military-sim in their apocalypses — MCs who don't just won't ever need to use **follow through**. And like I keep saying, that's cool, that's OK.

Answer (score 1):

Follow through is different from Help/Interfere in that *it is made in relation to a move already done*, and you follow through on the *consequences of that move.*

### An Example with NPC

**Taylor** (PC) and **Mag** (NPC) are at a standoff on a rickety one-man bridge, and Taylor decides that he's had enough trying to get him to peacefully back down, and goes aggro on him, but rolls a 7.  Mag decides to do what he should have done to begin with, and begins to back off.  His blood up, Taylor decides that's just not enough, and continues forward, taking advantage of the fact that Mag is more concentrated on Taylor than where he's going.

### An Example with a PC

**Taylor's** back is against the wall- Mag's mate **Oz** caught him out, and isn't looking for anything but Taylor's blood.  Luckily for him, **Goggles** was watching his back, and takes a shot at Oz to seize the upper hand, rolling an 8. Goggles chooses to take definite hold of the upper hand, and impress the enemy.

The gunshot pings off the ground behind Oz, and he realizes that could have been him.  Taylor's again into not leaving any enemies behind, so follows through on Goggles move to take Oz out.

Comment: The NPC example: whose move is Taylor following through on? I also don't see how the examples count as battles with bullets flying.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie - In the NPC example, Taylor is following through on Mags move, i.e. he chose to back down.  It's not just the PCs maneuvering that can be followed through on... the ebb and flow of combat goes both ways.  And yes, the examples were simplified to make the flow more clear, though I didn't read it as it had to be a full out battle- just that they were optional moves if the narrative called for them, as you pointed out in your excellent answer.

Comment: I believe they are limited to actual, full-scale battles, in the sense that a literal battle has to be part of the fiction before the battle moves can be brought in. The first line is an excellent answer that clears up the difference, but I think the examples could be much better. :)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie - point taken.  I'll try to make the examples a bit more concrete.